# What changes would allow cutting mRNA-based vaccine safety testing to 18 Months

Tags: coronavirus, vaccination, clinical-trial

I see a lot of skepticism among my fellow citizens following an interview that Bill Gates gave the BBC on the topic of Corona vaccines. The Gates foundation is funding several study ventures on Corona vaccines, conventional vaccines as well as experimental mRNA vaccines. In the interview he said:

> "We'll need to fund the ten most promising constructs because we don't know in advance which on will prove to be safe and effective [...] so we gonna have to take something that usually takes five or six years and get it done in 18 months [(6:09)](https://youtu.be/ie6lRKAdvuY?t=369)
>   [...]
>   There is an approach called RNA Vaccine [...]
>   that looks quite promising but we can't count on that, so we'll back 4 or 5 of that and 4 or 5 using a conventional approach, which unfortunately, the schedule on that would probably not so quick. [(6:45)](https://youtu.be/ie6lRKAdvuY?t=395)

There are [people on the internet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfbbikCPoHk) that criticize that Gates would want to trade security for speed in getting the vaccine out and cite this comparison (18 months instead of five years) to make a point how unsafe that would be. I interpret the interview insofar that Gates believes that the new technology itself would provide for some speed gains (longer time needed with conventional approaches). Similarly, [this review](https://www.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5906799/#S18title) (Section "Good manufacturing practice production") mentions that mRNA vaccines are easier to produce than their conventional counterparts, for example because life viruses and toxic inactivation chemicals are not involved in the process and thus do not need to be removed reliably.

However, I lack the knowledge to judge **how big the speed gains due to the mRNA platform could be**. Also, the same review as above mentions in the section "Safety" that there are more problems in clinical trials than there were in preclinical ones, so there still seems to be considerable need for basic research left. Similarly, I do not know **how long the phase of vaccine clinical trials normally is** and **how much it could be reduced by logistics** without loss of information. Finally I don't know **what studies could be left out for an emergency approval** of the vaccine to cut the approval time if the benefit would outweigh the risk.

I would be grateful if you could help me on the questions in **bold**.